# Переход на с формы на форму JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

Создаю приложение в netbeans и потребовался график для этого добавил в проект "Главный класс JavaFX". В нём всё что нужно реализовал.

Вопрос: как перейти на эту самую форму с основного приложения?

По другим формам реализовывал переход так:

```
Class form = new Class();
dispose();
form.setVisible(true);
```

где:
Class - это класс формы на которую хочу перейти.

P.S. Уверен что есть способы проще или лучше (и если есть добрые и опытные люди то скажите как лучше). Я знаю что ответ какой-то лёгкий но блин не знаю какой)) Заранее спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1):

```
GraphFX graph = new GraphFX();
dispose();
graph.main(null);
```